# Starting 3D printing at home

Tags: prusa-i3

I've been doing some 3D printing at work as a means of different tool holding devices and jigs and from this time I have gained some, although very basic, knowledge on how the printers work and how to troubleshoot the issues I've experienced with problems I have encountered.

From this I have gained a new interest in 3D printing as a result and would like to buy a printer for use at home that is relatively cheap (£300 Max-ish) and I'm wondering if anyone can give me some pointers as to which I should look into buying as a good first step to 3D printing at home.

I've been printing with a Prusa i3 MK3S+ at work and their PETG filament mainly, and I'm definitely leaning towards something similar and compatible with the PrusaSlicer because I'm fairly comfortable with both, but the i3 MK3S+ is a bit expensive for me to invest in for at home as of right now.

If anyone can help me out it would be greatly appreciated along with any set up tips for the printer you suggest

Many thanks.

Comment: Hi and welcome. Unfortunately shopping recommendations are off-topic (across the whole Stack Exchange network), as they can rapidly become out-of-date - so as it currently stands, your question will probably be closed. If you could [edit] your question (somehow) to make it less of a recommendation question, then that *might* help. Please see the on-topic pages in the [help/on-topic] and take the [tour].

Answer (score 0):

Reading between the lines, you require a started printer functionally equivalent to a Prusa i3 MK3, but on a limited budget as it was designed using the same original source material

The Ender 3 is probably your best bet, though this kind of question is not really what this website is designed to be used for.